# Click a Link working in Selenium Ide but not working in Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

I am testing  a scenario  for the  site "https://www.freecrm.com/index.html"

**login credentials [ john2013 / john2013 ]**

```
Scenario :

1 open the site https://www.freecrm.com/index.html

2 login  with valid credentials

3 click on the "New Contacts" link

4 Add new contacts
```

using Selenium ide  i am able to login and click on the "New Contact" link , but when i am trying to do the same thing using Webdriver [ java] i am not able to click  the "New Contact" link

the code i have written is given below

```
driver.findElement(By.name("username")).clear()     
driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("john2013");
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("john2013");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=\"image\"]")).click();
```

The code up to the above is working fine but clicking the "New Contact" link

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='noprint']/span[@class='headertext']/a[3]/")).click();
```

is not working though the same xpath is working in IDE.

i have tried with expected condition option , sleep   but nothing is working.

can any one help me in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your page uses a frameset. You should tell your webdriver which frame to use when it will search for your element. So try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("username")).clear()     
driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("john2013");
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("john2013");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=\"image\"]")).click();

//switch the driver to use one of the frames on your page. Potentially wait for a bit till the page is loaded
driver.switchTo().frame("mainpanel");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='New Contact']")).click();
```

Comment: 1. `driver.switchTo().frame("mainpanel");`, not `window` I suppose. 2. OP's XPath is wrong, but `//*[text()='New Contact']` probably isn't the best (using XPath is slower, using text is language dependent). Find it by `href` with XPath/CssSelector would be better. `By.cssSelector(".navlink[href*='action=contact&sub=load']")`

Comment: You are right. I changed the window to frame in my answer. Also with regards to xpath you are totally correct that using text is not the best way. I just wanted to show using a shorter xpath than the one currently used is an option. Thanks.

Comment: By.cssSelector(".navlink[href*='action=contact&sub=load']")  this is working for me to click the New Contact link.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the xpath of link to

```
xpath=//a[contains(text(),'<whatevertext>')]
```

Incase if the same text link is already present in some part o the page we can proceed with occurences. Example if it is repeating second time:

```
xpath=(//a[contains(text(),'<whatevertext>')])[2]
```

If Nothing is working the best way is through java script executor.

First get the webelement of the link.

Then use the following code"
    webelement=driver.findElement(by.xpath("=//a[contains(text(),'')]
    "))
    (JavaScriptExecutor)driver.executescript("argument[0].click();",webelement)

Answer (score 0):

Actually Speaking //div[@class='noprint']/span[@class='headertext']/a[3]/ is absolute XPath.

as it ends with a[3] the position will vary always so it is advisable to use relative XPath/CSS

Suggested CSS:css=.noprint > .headertext > a.classname
Another Suggested CSS: css=.noprint > .headertext > a[attribute='value']

So we can use either of the above format.